# Understanding $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N + 1)$ notation in cryptography paper

Tags: notation

I can't seem to understand what $A_{N,q}$ represents in [this paper (Section 2.1 - Notations)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/207.pdf). More specifically, I'm struggling to grasp the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N + 1)$. Could someone please explain it to me?

> $\lfloor . \rfloor$ represents the ceiling function.
>
> $\mathbb Z_q = \mathbb Z \cap [-\lfloor\frac{q}{2}\rfloor, \lfloor\frac{q}{2}\rfloor]$ for $q \ge 2$.
>
> For a 2-power number $N$, and $q > 0$, we write $A_{N,q}$ to denote the set of integer polynomials $A_{N,q} = \mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N + 1)$.

Comment: It is the ring of polynomials (in indeterminate X) over the field Z_q (integers modulo q), modulo the polynomial X^N + 1 where N is some power of 2. It is a [_cyclotomic ring_](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicField.html) that frequently shows up in Ring-LWE and other hard lattice problems over Rings due to its admittance of fast Ring operations using FFT-like techniques.

Comment: @pod can you convert this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm struggling to grasp the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N + 1)$

Apologies if I'm coming at this at an overly basic level - I'm not sure where in your mathematical studies you are, and so I thought it would be better to underestimate your initial understanding...

This stands for a specific mathematical [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), that is, a set of values with addition and multiplication operations defined (that meet certain properties).

To see what ring it is, let us break it down:

- $\mathbb{Z}_q$

That's the ring of integers modulo $q$.  That is, it is the integers, except that we consider two integers $a, b$ to be the same if $a-b = kq$ for some integer $k$.

We normally represent values in such a ring as values between 0 and $q-1$; however the paper specifically cites that they will be using the alternative representation of values between $-\lfloor q/2 \rfloor$ and $\lfloor q/2 \rfloor$.  This alternative representation doesn't change the mathematical properties of the ring; however it may be important if they do operations that depend on the specific values.

- $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]$

This is the ring of polynomials over a single artificial variable $X$, where all the coefficients of the polynomial are members of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Members of this ring include $X^2 + 2 \cdot X + 1$ and $X^{19} - 7 X^{5}$ (given that $1, 2$, and $-7$ are members of $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Addition and multiplication in this ring is defined pretty much like addition and multiplication of polynomials over the reals, except that coefficient computations are done using $\mathbb{Z}_q$ operations.

- $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N + 1)$

This is the above ring modulo the polynomial $X^N+1$.  That is, we consider two polynomials $P(X)$ and $Q(X)$ to be the same if $P(X) - Q(X) = R(X) \times (X^N+1)$ for some polynomial $R(X)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]$.

With this ring, for any polynomial $P(X)$, there will be a unique polynomial $Q(X)$ of degree at most $N-1$ where $P(X) = Q(X)$ (using the above criteria).  It is easy to find this polynomial $Q(X)$, and so is usually used as the canonical representation.

As mentioned in the comments, such a ring is called a cyclotomic ring, and has a number of interesting properties I won't delve into - this should give you both a taste and a direction to do more study, should you want to.

Comment: Addition: The answer's polynomial $Q(X)\in\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N+1)$ can be represented by the vector of $N$ integers in $\bigl[-\left\lfloor q/2\right\rfloor,\left\lfloor q/2\right\rfloor\bigr]$ of the coefficients of Q[X] (e.g. from constant term to coefficient of the term of degree $N-1$). A computer implementation would do that. The set $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N+1)$ has $q^N$ elements.